# multiprocessing.Pool: What's the difference between map_async and imap?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn how to use Python's `multiprocessing` package, but I don't understand the difference between `map_async` and `imap`.
I noticed that both `map_async` and `imap` are executed asynchronously. So when should I use one over the other? And how should I retrieve the result returned by `map_async`?

Should I use something like this?

```
def test():
    result = pool.map_async()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result.get()

result=test()
for i in result:
    print i
```

Answer (score 708, accepted):

There are two key differences between `imap`/`imap_unordered` and `map`/`map_async`:

1. The way they consume the iterable you pass to them.
2. The way they return the result back to you.

`map` consumes your iterable by converting the iterable to a list (assuming it isn't a list already), breaking it into chunks, and sending those chunks to the worker processes in the `Pool`. Breaking the iterable into chunks performs better than passing each item in the iterable between processes one item at a time - particularly if the iterable is large. However, turning the iterable into a list in order to chunk it can have a very high memory cost, since the entire list will need to be kept in memory.

`imap` doesn't turn the iterable you give it into a list, nor does break it into chunks (by default). It will iterate over the iterable one element at a time, and send them each to a worker process. This means you don't take the memory hit of converting the whole iterable to a list, but it also means the performance is slower for large iterables, because of the lack of chunking. This can be mitigated by passing a `chunksize` argument larger than default of 1, however.

The other major difference between `imap`/`imap_unordered` and `map`/`map_async`, is that with `imap`/`imap_unordered`, you can start receiving results from workers as soon as they're ready, rather than having to wait for all of them to be finished. With `map_async`, an `AsyncResult` is returned right away, but you can't actually retrieve results from that object until all of them have been processed, at which points it returns the same list that `map` does (`map` is actually implemented internally as `map_async(...).get()`). There's no way to get partial results; you either have the entire result, or nothing.

`imap` and `imap_unordered` both return iterables right away. With `imap`, the results will be yielded from the iterable as soon as they're ready, while still preserving the ordering of the input iterable. With `imap_unordered`, results will be yielded as soon as they're ready, regardless of the order of the input iterable. So, say you have this:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def func(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x + 2

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    start = time.time()
    for x in p.imap(func, [1,5,3]):
        print("{} (Time elapsed: {}s)".format(x, int(time.time() - start)))
```

This will output:

```
3 (Time elapsed: 1s)
7 (Time elapsed: 5s)
5 (Time elapsed: 5s)
```

If you use `p.imap_unordered` instead of `p.imap`, you'll see:

```
3 (Time elapsed: 1s)
5 (Time elapsed: 3s)
7 (Time elapsed: 5s)
```

If you use `p.map` or `p.map_async().get()`, you'll see:

```
3 (Time elapsed: 5s)
7 (Time elapsed: 5s)
5 (Time elapsed: 5s)
```

So, the primary reasons to use `imap`/`imap_unordered` over `map_async` are:

1. Your iterable is large enough that converting it to a list would cause you to run out of/use too much memory.
2. You want to be able to start processing the results before *all* of them are completed.

Comment: what about apply and apply_async ?

Comment: @HarshDaftary `apply` sends a single task off to a worker process, and then blocks until it's complete. `apply_async` sends a single task off to a work process, and then immediately returns an `AsyncResult` object, which can be used to wait for the task to finish and retrieve the result. `apply` is implemented by simply calling `apply_async(...).get()`

Comment: That's the kind of description which should be in the official `Pool` documentation rather than [the existing dull one](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

Comment: @dano I want to run a function in the background but I have some resource limitations and cannot run the function as many times that I want and want to queue the extra executions of the function. Do you have any idea on how I should do that? I have my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081260/executing-a-function-in-the-background-while-using-limited-number-of-cores-threa). Could you please take a look at my question and see if you can give me some hints (or even better, an answer) on how I should do that?

Comment: If using `imap` (ordered), do workers that finish "out of order" wait for preceding workers to finish before starting on the next piece of work? Or do they begin the next piece of work immediately after finishing the previous one, and leave it up to the `Pool` to ensure that the results returned are in order?

Comment: @BallpointBen It will move on to the next piece of work as soon as it's done. Ordering is handled back in the parent process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708371/purpose-of-pool-join-pool-close-in-python-multiprocessing

Comment: What happens if you don't care about returning a result at all and, say, the results of the process are written to disk for later use?

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer states that for `imap_unordered` "results will be yielded as soon as they're ready" where one might possibly infer that results will be returned in the order of completion. But I just want to make it clear that this is not true *in general*. The documentation states that the results are returned in *arbitrary* order. Consider the following program that uses a pool size of 4, an *iterable* size of 20 and a *chunksize* value of 5. The worker function sleeps a variable amount of time depending on its passed argument, which also ensures that no one process in the pool grabs all the submitted tasks. Thus I expect each process in the pool to have `20 / 4 = 5` tasks to process:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def worker(x):
    print(f'x = {x}', flush=True)
    time.sleep(.1 * (20 - x))
    # return approximate completion time with passed argument:
    return time.time(), x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    results = pool.imap_unordered(worker, range(20), chunksize=5)
    for t, x in results:
        print('result:', t, x)
```

Prints:

```
x = 0
x = 5
x = 10
x = 15
x = 16
x = 17
x = 11
x = 18
x = 19
x = 6
result: 1621512513.7737606 15
result: 1621512514.1747007 16
result: 1621512514.4758775 17
result: 1621512514.675989 18
result: 1621512514.7766125 19
x = 12
x = 1
x = 13
x = 7
x = 14
x = 2
result: 1621512514.2716103 10
result: 1621512515.1721854 11
result: 1621512515.9727488 12
result: 1621512516.6744206 13
result: 1621512517.276999 14
x = 8
x = 9
x = 3
result: 1621512514.7695887 5
result: 1621512516.170747 6
result: 1621512517.4713914 7
result: 1621512518.6734042 8
result: 1621512519.7743165 9
x = 4
result: 1621512515.268784 0
result: 1621512517.1698637 1
result: 1621512518.9698756 2
result: 1621512520.671273 3
result: 1621512522.2716706 4
```

You can plainly see that these results are not being yielded in completion order. For example, I have been returned `1621512519.7743165 9` followed by `1621512515.268784 0`, which was returned by the worker function more than 4 seconds earlier than the previously returned result.  However, if I change the *chunksize* value to 1, the printout becmomes:

```
x = 0
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
result: 1621513028.888357 3
x = 5
result: 1621513028.9863524 2
x = 6
result: 1621513029.0838938 1
x = 7
result: 1621513029.1825204 0
x = 8
result: 1621513030.4842813 7
x = 9
result: 1621513030.4852195 6
x = 10
result: 1621513030.4872172 5
x = 11
result: 1621513030.4892178 4
x = 12
result: 1621513031.3908074 11
x = 13
result: 1621513031.4895358 10
x = 14
result: 1621513031.587289 9
x = 15
result: 1621513031.686152 8
x = 16
result: 1621513032.1877549 15
x = 17
result: 1621513032.1896958 14
x = 18
result: 1621513032.1923752 13
x = 19
result: 1621513032.1923752 12
result: 1621513032.2935638 19
result: 1621513032.3927407 18
result: 1621513032.4912949 17
result: 1621513032.5884912 16
```

This *is* in completion order. However, I hesitate to state that `imap_unordered` *will always* return results as they become available *if* a *chunksize* value of 1 is specified, although that appears to be the case based on this experiment, since the documentation makes no such claim.

**Discussion**

When a *chunksize* of 5 is specified, the 20 tasks are placed on a single input queue for the 4 processes in the pool to process in chunks of size 5. So a process that becomes idle will take off the queue the next chunk of 5 tasks and process each one of them in turn before becoming idle again. Thus the first process will be processing `x` arguments 0 through 4, the second process `x` arguments 5 through 9, etc. This is why you see the initial `x` values printed as 0, 5, 10 and 15.

But while the result for `x` argument 0 completes before the result for `x` argument 9, it would appear that results get written out together as chunks and therefore the result for `x` argument 0 will not get returned until the results for the `x` arguments that were queued up in the same chunk (i.e. 1, 2, 3 and 4) are also available.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point. And I agree with your observation that it looks like a giben result value is only made available to the parent when the entire chunk it is a part of has completed.