# Does joblib.Parallel keep the original order of data passed?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

I want to ask the same question as
[Python 3: does Pool keep the original order of data passed to map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273960/python-3-does-pool-keep-the-original-order-of-data-passed-to-map) for joblib. E.g.:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in x)
```

The syntax kind of implied it but I am always worried about the ordering of output of parallel processing and I don't want to code base on undocumented behavior.

Comment: It would be nice if we could feed it a nested list of jobs or a dictionary of jobs and it would return the results in the same structure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Per the joblib documentation](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html) you can specify the `backend` as`multiprocessing` which is based on `multiprocessing.Pool`. Then the other answer would apply that the results are in fact ordered.

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2, backend="multiprocessing")(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in x)
```

By default, however, they use [loky](https://loky.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and it isn't immediately clear but it could be detected by implementing tests.

Comment: My tests with the loky backend show that it also returns the results in order.

Answer (score 29):

TL;DR - it preserves order for both backends.

Extending @Chris Farr's answer, I implemented a simple test. I make a function wait for some random amount of time (you can check these wait times are not identical). I get that the order is preserved every time, with both backends.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np
import time

def f(wait):
    time.sleep(wait)
    return wait

n = 50
waits = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=n)
res = Parallel(n_jobs=8, backend='multiprocessing')(delayed(f)(wait) for wait in waits)
np.all(res == waits)
```