# Purpose of pool.join, pool.close in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading

In the link below there is an explanation of the `map` method on the `Pool` class.

It seems that it *blocks* until the result is ready. This implies that there is no need to do `pool.close(); pool.join()` after running `pool.map`, however it is demo'd in this way in [this](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/) blog.

Am I missing something or is there a need to do pool.close after running `pool.map` (as opposed to `pool.map_async`?  Note I am using `[multiprocessing.dummy][2]`, which is provides a similar api to multiprocessing, but uses threading under the covers.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`pool.close` tells the pool not to accept any new job.

`pool.join` tells the pool to wait until all jobs finished then exit, effectively cleaning up the pool.

So blocking the parent process is just a side effect of what `pool.join` is doing.

It's true that when you call `pool.map()`, the parent process is blocked until map returns result. But it's a good practice to `close` and `join` the `pool` after using it, to better manage resource and control exceptions.

Comment: Note that if you use a Pool as a context manager, it will handle calling `close` and `terminate` for you.

Comment: @hlongmore How to use Pool as context manager?

Comment: If I don't have anything to join can I only use pool.close()?

Comment: @Coddy You can use context manager for the pool by `with multiprocessing.Pool(n) as pool: ...`. The `pool` will be closed and joined automatically when the process leaves the `with` code block.

Comment: @Coddy What THN said.