# multiprocessing: map vs map_async

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

What's the difference between using `map` and `map_async`?  Are they not running the same function after distributing the items from the list to 4 processes?

So is it wrong to presume both are running asynchronous and parallel?

```
def f(x):
   return 2*x

p=Pool(4)
l=[1,2,3,4]
out1=p.map(f,l)
#vs
out2=p.map_async(f,l)
```

Comment: Doesn't `map` return only once the map is done (ie synchronously but in parallel), while `map_async` returns right away and allows the mapping to be done in the background (ie asynchronously and in parallel)?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

There are four choices to mapping jobs to processes. You have to consider multi-args, concurrency, blocking, and ordering. `map` and `map_async` only differ with respect to blocking. `map_async` is non-blocking where as `map` is blocking

So let's say you had a function

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    print(x*x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(f, range(10))
    r = pool.map_async(f, range(10))
    # DO STUFF
    print('HERE')
    print('MORE')
    r.wait()
    print('DONE')
```

Example output:

```
0
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
0
HERE
1
4
MORE
16
25
36
9
49
64
81
DONE
```

`pool.map(f, range(10))` will wait for all 10 of those function calls to finish so we see all the prints in a row.
`r = pool.map_async(f, range(10))` will execute them asynchronously and only block when `r.wait()` is called so we see `HERE` and `MORE` in between but `DONE` will always be at the end.

Comment: ok so if i dont have other tasks to do beside executing the function f over the list, then map and map_async are same

Comment: Not quite. You'll notice map will execute in order, but map_async doesn't

Comment: Should there be a `print 'DONE'` after `r.wait()`?

Comment: Yes there should be!

Comment: If above example doesn't return different results for `map` and `map_async` on first run, try setting `range(500)` or something large.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708371/purpose-of-pool-join-pool-close-in-python-multiprocessing

Comment: Hello, will this work with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments ? I am attempting to pass multiple args to the function.

Comment: @quikst3r: For me they both execute in random order. I change func f() to print(x), and the parameters:
"pool.map(f, range(11,20)); r = pool.map_async(f, range(10))"; 
After run the code, it return:
 "11
12
13
15
16
17
18
14
19
HERE
0
MORE
2
1
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
DONE"

Comment: If you don't see HERE and MORE and random positions you don't need to set range to a very high number and then keep scrolling for the prints. For me it was enough to set a `time.sleep(0.0002)`  right before the print part And increase range a little bit to 100

Comment: @Catbuilts Yeah, there is no difference in ordering between `map_async` and `map`, @quikst3r was mistaken when he said that. `map` is actually implemented internally as `map_async(...).get()`.