# Pool.map vs Pool.map_async

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the program like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
# I make a heavy code here to take time
  for i in range(10000):
     for i in range(10000):
        pass #do nothing

  print x #print x

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = Pool(processes=4)

  pool.map(f, range(10))
  r  = pool.map_async(f, range(10))

  # DO STUFF
  print 'HERE'
  print 'MORE'
  r.wait()
  print 'Done'
```

As far as I know,  `pool.map` will return in order, whereas `pool.map_async` will not. 
I tried to figure out the difference between them, but I haven't got it yet.

Accutually, I have read some posts, for example: [Python multiprocessing : map vs map_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908987/python-multiprocessing-map-vs-map-async)

but I'm still confused.
My questions are:

1. How difference between the 2 functions ?
2. When I run the code above, I got this:

> 1 3 2 0 4 6 5 7 8 9 HERE MORE 1 0 3 2 5 4 6 7 8 9 Done

I expect `pool.map` will return the output in order, but It didn't !
So, why didn't It return in order ? Or I misunderstood the function ?

3. I think when the `pool.map` was called, the main (the following code, like
   `r  = pool.map_async(f, range(10));`
   `print 'HERE';`
   `print 'MORE'`
   is continue running. So I expect "Here" and "More" is printed between the numbers, I mean something like

> 3 2 0 4 6  HERE 5 7 8 9 1 0 3 2 MORE  5 4 6 7 8 9 Done

But It happened in other way.
Why doesn't It run as I expect ?

4. If I comment the  *heavy code*, the `f` function now just is:

   `def f(x):`
     `print x`

then both the functions will return the output in order (I tried run a lot of times, It always print the same result.
So, Why does It behave differently when It does/doesn't have the *heavy code*.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
# I make a heavy code here to take time
  for i in range(10000):
     for i in range(10000):
        pass #do nothing
  print x
  return x 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = Pool(processes=4)

  print pool.map(f, range(10))
  r  = pool.map_async(f, range(10))

  # DO STUFF
  print 'HERE'
  print 'MORE'
  r.wait()
  print 'Done'
  print r.get()
```

1. `pool.map_async` will not block your script, whereas `pool.map` will (as mentioned by [quikst3r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35909364)).
2. I slightly adapted your script to be more illustrative. As you can see the final results are both in order, except that after starting `pool.map_async` subsequent code is executed as well. The output is:

   ```
   1
   3
   0
   2
   4
   5
   7
   6
   8
   9
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   HERE
   MORE
   3
   2
   1
   0
   5
   4
   6
   7
   8
   9
   Done
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   ```

Whereas the print order is hardly determined due to overhead in the job distribution and individual load of your cpus.