# `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` seems to schedule wrongly

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

I have a function which request a server, retrieves some data, process it and saves a csv file. This function should be launch 20k times. Each execution last differently: sometimes It last more than 20 minutes and other less than a second. I decided to go with `multiprocessing.Pool.map` to parallelize the execution. My code looks like:

```
def get_data_and_process_it(filename):
    print('getting', filename)
    ...
    print(filename, 'has been process')

with Pool(8) as p:
    p.map(get_data_and_process_it, long_list_of_filenames)
```

Looking at how `prints` are generated it seems that `long_list_of_filenames` it's been splited into 8 parts and assinged to each `CPU` because sometimes is just get blocked in one 20 minutes execution with no other element  of `long_list_of_filenames` been processed in those 20 minutes. What I was expecting is `map` to schedule each element in a cpu core in a FIFO style.

Is there a better approach for my case?

Comment: You should set the `chunksize`-parameter for `Pool.map()` to `1` in this case.  You can calculate the otherwise generated chunksizes with `calc_chunksize_info()` from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032744/9059420).

Comment: `map` works similar to the built-in `map` for iterables. That means that order is *ensured*. In other words, a slow process will block the faster processes. If order doesn't matter for you, I suggest looking into `map_async` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` method only returns when *all* operations have finished.

And printing from a pool worker  is not ideal. For one thing, files like `stdout` use buffering, so there might be a variable amount of time between printing a message and it actually appearing. Furthermore, since all workers inherit the same `stdout`, their output would become intermeshed and possibly even garbled.

So I would suggest using `imap_unordered` instead. That returns an iterator that will begin yielding results as soon as they are available. The only catch is that this returns results in the order they *finish*, not in the order they started.

Your worker function (`get_data_and_process_it`) should *return* some kind of status indicator. For example a tuple of the filename and the result.

```
def get_data_and_process_it(filename):
    ...
    if (error):
        return (filename, f'has *failed* bacause of {reason}')
    return (filename, 'has been processed')
```

You could then do:

```
with Pool(8) as p:
   for fn, res in p.imap_unordered(get_data_and_process_it, long_list_of_filenames):
       print(fn, res)
```

That gives accurate information about when a job finishes, and since only the parent process writes to `stdout`, there is no change of the output becoming garbled.

Additionally, I would suggest to use `sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)` somewhere in the beginning of your program. That ensures that the `stdout` stream will be flushed after every line of output.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is blocking, instead of `p.map` you can use `p.map_async`. `map` will wait for all those function calls to finish so we see all the results in a row. `map_async` does the work in random order and does not wait for a proceeding task to finish before starting a new task. This is the fastest approach.([For more](https://cslocumwx.github.io/blog/2015/02/23/python-multiprocessing/)) There is also a [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908987/multiprocessing-map-vs-map-async) which in detail discusses about `map` and `map_async`.

The multiprocessing Pool class handles the queuing logic for us. It's perfect for running web scraping jobs in parallel (example) or really any job that can be broken up and distributed independently. If you need more control over the queue or need to share data between multiple processes, you may want to look at the `Queue` class([For more](https://testdriven.io/blog/developing-an-asynchronous-task-queue-in-python/)).