# How to use multiprocessing in Python in this case?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I try to use simple way to make mulitiprocessing:

```
urls = [1, 2, 3, 4]
p = Pool(2)
p.map(open, urls)
```

Where `open()` is function, that does calculations.

```
def open(url):
    print(url)
```

When I do `print(url)` it returns me strange result:

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

I can assume that each of process `Pool(2)` handler the same calculations there is wrong.

I need that process 1 takes `[1, 2]` for handling and process 2 takes `[3, 4]`

Comment: you may check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520781/multiprocessing-pool-whats-the-difference-between-map-async-and-imap. Maybe `map` is too synchronous for you.

Comment: Don't use `open` as a function name, it's a builtin. Also, are you on Windows?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments

Comment: @Peter234 there aren't multiple arguments though? It's meant to take an iterable, which `urls` is.

Comment: You're not joining or closing the pool in this code. Is this an accurate representation of your approach? Granted I'm on Windows so I've had to shield with `if __name__ == '__main__':` but currently I get no printouts at all, and zombie processes.

Comment: No, I run script on Cent OS

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want to:

```
import multiprocessing
def func(x):
    return x[0] + x[1]

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    for x in p.map(func, [(1, 2), (3, 4)]):
        print(x)
```

output:

```
 3
 7
```