# Multiprocessing using Pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing (in any language), and I'm learning how to implement it particularly in Python. A typical example given is something such as:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
 

def compute(x):
    return x * x
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as p:
        res = p.map(compute, [1, 2, 3, 4])
    print(res)  # prints [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

To me, it seems like the function `compute` does `x=1` first, followed by `x=2`, then `x=3`, and finally `x=4` before terminating and returning the result. Or does the above code simultaneously call `compute` in separate cores for x = 1, 2, 3, and 4 (i.e., four separate `compute` calls)?

Granted, this example is very trivial and an overkill for multiprocessing, but I will any clarification about what `Pool` does. Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/26521507/8366805

Comment: Have you read the documentation before asking SO to repeat it here? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiprocessing.Pool: What's the difference between map\_async and imap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520781/multiprocessing-pool-whats-the-difference-between-map-async-and-imap)

Comment: As you suspect, the code simultaneously calls `compute` in separate cores for each of the values; it limits the number of workers to the parameter passed to the `Pool()` constructor, or the number of CPU cores, though, so if the list has more items, it'll pass them to the workers as they become available. (It also works in chunks, rather than handling single items, to reduce the amount of overhead.)