Polars: how to partition a big dataframe and save each one in parallel
I have a big Polars dataframe with a lot of groups. Now, I want to partition the dataframe by group and save all sub-dataframes. I can easily do this as follows:
for d in df.partition_by(["group1", "group2"]):
    d.write_csv(f"~/{d[0, 'group1']}_{d[0, 'group2']}.csv")

However, the approach above is sequential and slow when the df is very large and has a whole lot of partitions.
Is there any Polars native way to parallelize it (the code section above)?
If not, how can I do it in a Python native way instead?

As far as I am aware, Polars does not currently offer a way to parallelize .write_*() / .sink_*() calls.
For Parquet files, this would be similar to writing a "Hive Partitioned Dataset":

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11500
https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/15441 # CSV Hive partitioning

Multiprocessing
In my own testing - a ProcessPool has performed slightly faster than a ThreadPool for this task.
With Polars + multiprocessing - you need to use get_context("spawn")

See: https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/misc/multiprocessing/

import polars as pl
from multiprocessing import get_context
# from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # <- threadpool

def write_csv(args):
    group, df = args
    df.write_csv(f"{group}.csv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    df = pl.DataFrame({
        "group": [1, 2, 1],
        "val": ["a", "b", "c"]
    })
    
    with get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
        groups = df.group_by("group")
        results = pool.map(write_csv, groups) # this is lazy
        
        # we must consume `results` - use empty for loop
        for result in results: 
            ... 


(note: You can use group_by instead of partition_by)

Pool() methods
There's a lot of discussion out there about the different Pool methods to use:

.map
.imap
.imap_unordered

In my simple testing, .map produced the fastest results - with similar memory usage.
But depending on your data size + system specs, you may need to investigate the others:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26521507



how can I do it in a Python native way instead?

Throw those rows into a suitably indexed RDBMS table,
such as postgres or even sqlite.
Now you have a trivial problem.
Ask a Pool
of child worker processes to each extract
a different group and write the results to a .csv file.
A typical pythonic way to accomplish that would be via
sqlalchemy.
For quick-n-dirty the {polars, pandas}
convenience functions to issue a SELECT and then
write out a .csv would work just fine,
albeit with larger memory footprint than if
we're streaming rows to the filesystem.

This is probably a better use case for the pyarrow dataset writer. It will open up-to all the destination files at once and write to them as it reads the data.
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

ds.write_dataset(df.to_arrow(), 'output_dir', partitioning=['group1','group2'], format='csv')

It'll put the files in 'output_dir/{group_1_value}/{group_2_value}/part-{x}.csv' so you'll have to move/rename them (possibly combine multiple parts into one them) after the fact. Something like
from pathlib import Path
for g1 in Path('output_dir').iterdir():
    for g2 in Path(g1).iterdir():
        files =  list(Path(g2).iterdir()):
        if len(files)==1:
            oldname = str(files[0]).split('/')
            newname = f"~/{oldname[1]}_{oldname[2]}.csv"
            files[0].rename(newname)
        else:
            print(f"need to combine files at {g2}")     

